# MongoDB. Aggregate the sum of two arrays sizes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

With MongoDB 3.4.10 and mongoose 4.13.6 I'm able to count sizes of two arrays on the User model:

```
User.aggregate()
  .project({
    '_id': 1,
    'leftVotesCount': { '$size': '$leftVoted' },
    'rightVotesCount': { '$size': '$rightVoted' }
  })
```

where my Users are (per `db.users.find()`)

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2b21e63023c6117085c240"), "rightVoted" : [ 2 ],
>   "leftVoted" : [ 1, 6 ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2c0d68efde3416bc8b7020"), "rightVoted" : [ 2 ],
>   "leftVoted" : [ 1 ] }

Here I'm getting expected result:

> [ { _id: '5a2b21e63023c6117085c240', leftVotesCount: 2, rightVotesCount: 1 },
>
> { _id: '5a2c0d68efde3416bc8b7020', leftVotesCount: 1, rightVotesCount: 1 } ]

**Question**. How can I get a cumulative value of `leftVotesCount` and `rightVotesCount` data? I tried folowing:

```
User.aggregate()
  .project({
    '_id': 1,
    'leftVotesCount': { '$size': '$leftVoted' },
    'rightVotesCount': { '$size': '$rightVoted' },
    'votesCount': { '$add': [ '$leftVotesCount', '$rightVotesCount' ] },
    'votesCount2': { '$sum': [ '$leftVotesCount', '$rightVotesCount' ] }
  })
```

But `votesCount` is `null` and `votesCount2` is `0` for both users. I'm expecting `votesCount = 3` for User 1 and `votesCount = 2` for User 2.

Answer (score 3):

`$leftVotesCount`, `$rightVotesCount` become available only on the next stage. Try something like:

```
User.aggregate()
  .project({
    '_id': 1,
    'leftVotesCount': { '$size': '$leftVoted' },
    'rightVotesCount': { '$size': '$rightVoted' }
  })
  .project({
    '_id': 1,
    'leftVotesCount': 1,
    'rightVotesCount': 1
    'votesCount': { '$add': [ '$leftVotesCount', '$rightVotesCount' ] },
    'votesCount2': { '$sum': [ '$leftVotesCount', '$rightVotesCount' ] }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I'll make a note of that! meanwhile I found a way how to get the result in a single step without `leftVotesCount` and `rightVotesCount`...

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference the project variables created in the same project stage.

You can wrap the variables in a [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) expression.

```
User.aggregate().project({
  "$let": {
    "vars": {
      "leftVotesCount": {
        "$size": "$leftVoted"
      },
      "rightVotesCount": {
        "$size": "$rightVoted"
      }
    },
    "in": {
      "votesCount": {
        "$add": [
          "$$leftVotesCount",
          "$$rightVotesCount"
        ]
      },
      "leftVotesCount": "$$leftVotesCount",
      "rightVotesCount": "$$rightVotesCount"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that `$add` supports nested expressions, so I was able to solve the issue by excluding intermediate variables:

```
User.aggregate().project({
  '_id': 1,
  'votesCount': { '$add': [ { '$size': '$leftVoted' }, { '$size': '$rightVoted' } ] }
});

// [ {_id: '...', votesCount: 3}, {_id: '...', votesCount: 2} ]
```